# python unittest faulty module

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have a module that I need to test in python.

I'm using the unittest framework but I ran into a problem.

The module has some method definitions, one of which is used when it's imported (readConfiguration) like so:

```
.
.
.
def readConfiguration(file = "default.xml"):
    # do some reading from xml

readConfiguration()
```

This is a problem because when I try to import the module it also tries to run the "readConfiguration" method which fails the module and the program (a configuration file does not exist in the test environment).

I'd like to be able to test the module independent of any configuration files.

I didn't write the module and it **cannot** be re-factored.

I know I can include a dummy configuration file but I'm looking for a "cleaner", more elegant, solution.

Comment: There is no cleaner solution; this is one of those things you cannot patch out at runtime.

Comment: Without more information, there really is not much we can help you with. But it seems that if you want to work around this, you will need to patch, modify, or refactor the module. There is no magical solution.

Comment: patch as in re-factor?

Comment: Yes, Inbar meant refactor. Forcing a config load at import time is terribly bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have already pointed out, imports should never have side effects, so try to get the module changed if at all possible.

If you really, absolutely, cannot do this, there might be another way: let `readConfiguration()` be called, but stub out its dependencies. For instance, if it uses the builtin `open()` function, you could mock that, as demonstrated in the [`mock` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.mock-examples.html):

```
>>> mock = MagicMock(return_value=sentinel.file_handle)
>>> with patch('builtins.open', mock):
...     import the_broken_module
...     # do your testing here
```

Replace `sentinel.file_handle` with `StringIO("<contents of mock config file>")` if you need to supply actual content.

It's brittle as it depends on the implementation of `readConfiguration()`, but if there really is no other way, it might be useful as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice patch but probably does not fit a standard unittest structure.

I may resort to it if re-factoring will not be approved after re-examination but for now it's on hold as no good solution was suggested (other than... re-factoring).

Comment: If you need it from more than one test method, you can do this in the `setUp()` method of your unittest class, and do e.g. `import the_broken_module; self.the_broken_module = the_broken_module`. You can then access it from test methods as `self.the_broken_module`. Once imported, any subsequent imports won't have any effect but don't do any harm either.

Comment: It seems to work (the program doesn't break, but no tests are written yet). If we'll end up using it I'll let you know how well it did.

Thanks!